# Match output results with text file

Tags: regex, bash, grep

So i would like to know, how am i able to match an output results with the text file content.
For example i have an output like these:

```
admins
workers
example
devs
back-office
```

and then i have a text file (groups-id.txt) which containing something like this:

```
admins,1
apple,2
sample-text,3
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
hr-admins,8
```

I try to grep like this. But it will contain the hr-admins group aswell because of admins word.

```
grep -Ew -i "admins|workers|example|devs|back-office" groups-id.txt
```

How am i able to grep these words with there numbers(id)?

As of results i would like to have something like this:

```
admins,1
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using extended matching. Just specify the patterns start at the beginning of the line.

```
$: grep -Ew -i "^(admins|workers|example|devs|back-office)" groups-id.txt
admins,1
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
```

You might also want to save yourself the trouble of wondering how `grep` is going to parse "words" with `-w` and just explicitly include the following delimiter.

```
$: grep -Ei "^(admins|workers|example|devs|back-office)," groups-id.txt
admins,1
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
```

Comment: Hi, Thats almost solve my problem, when i tested out i got a result like this:
$: grep -Ew -i "^(admins|back)" groups-id.txt
admins,1
back-office,7
back-room,8
back,9

It gives me the "back-office" and "back-room" result but i just want the "back" and "admins" results.

Comment: Edited. Try it without the `-w`. Explicit boundaries reduce accidental misparsing.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{f1[$1]; next} $1 in f1' file1.txt file2.txt 
admins,1
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
```

Explanation:

```
-F,              # set the field separator to a comma
NR==FNR          # idiomatic awkism that tests if this is the first file
  {f1[$1]; next} # if so, store that word into an associative array
$1 in f1         # if the first field of second file has been seen
                 # then print the record
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner for this question, using only `join` and `sort` utilities, would be

```
join -t, <(sort groups-id.txt) <(sort groups)
```

where the contents of the file `groups` is

```
admins
workers
example
devs
back-office
```

and that of the file `groups-id.txt` is as in the question, the output is

```
admins,1
back-office,7
devs,6
example,5
workers,4
```

The only caveat is that the order is different than that of the original files; output is ordered by group names. It can be ordered numerically by group ids:

```
join -t, <(sort groups-id.txt) <(sort groups) | sort -n -t, -k2
```

Output of the above is

```
admins,1
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
```

If names of selected groups are produced by a command then simply replace the `sort groups` with `command_for_group_names | sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create patterns that match the entire first field - so the key word "admins" needs to become the pattern "^admins,"

Say the keys are in a file called keys.txt

```
admins
workers
example
devs
back-office
```

Then use sed to create the patterns on the fly and feed to grep using bash process substitution

```sh
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/,/' keys.txt) groups-id.txt
```

gives

```
admins,1
workers,4
example,5
devs,6
back-office,7
```